# How can I pass on my Bash loop variable to the Perl?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, centos

I'm trying to replace string in many files using the script below but I can't pass the value of `i` to `perl` as the following is passing the first file name in the folder

```
for i in `ls | awk -F".conf" '{print $1}'`
do
export i

/usr/bin/perl -p -i -w -e 's/error_log \/dev\/null crit;/error_log \/var\/log\/nginx\/$ENV{i}_error error;\n/g;' *


done
```

Any advice would be appreciated?
Thanks

Comment: Why export when you can append the variable to the string argument you are passing to Perl?

Comment: @amine.ahd can you explain more? i tried without the export but the value comes empty! liek this:
/usr/bin/perl -p -i -w -e 's/error_log \/dev\/null crit;/error_log \/var\/log\/nginx\/${i}_error error;\n/g;' *

Comment: Why not do it all in perl?

Comment: did you try to print the value of `$i` to be sure it is not empty?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it as a command-line argument. Note the correct way to iterate over the config files.

```
for i in *.conf; do
    f=${i%.conf}
    perl -piwe 's|error_log /dev/null crit;|error_log /var/log/nginx/$ARGV[0]_error error;\n|g;' "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not that your bash code passes only the first file in the folder.

The loop actually passes through all the file names, but the substitution in the Perl command only matches the first time it is called.

At the first iteration you replace all occurrences of the string `error_log /dev/null crit;` with something else in ***all files***. Thereafter there is no longer a `error_log /dev/null crit;` to be found, so the second and subsequent iterations fail to make any changes.